# RecyclerView with dynamic sized elements

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make the switch from listview to recyclerview but can't seem to figure out how best to recycle views. What I would like is a set of cardviews in a cardview. The data set resembles a bunch of students in different classes. Every class has different sizes and they are to be represented in the same card.

What I have at the moment is the following xml where 'tv1' will contain the title of the class and the student names are dynamically added in 'card_ll'. The problem I am having is that I inflate the view for each student name manually and add / clear the linearlayout depending on how many students there are in the class. Note, the number of students is non-zero but cannot be determined beforehand.

Is there a way to reuse the views of each student card?

Thanks

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter onBindViewHolder implementation

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     final ClassType ec = mDataset.get(position);
    final String name = ec.classtitle;

    holder.tv1.setText(ec.header1);

    if( ec.studentlist!=null && ec.studentlist.size()>0) {
        holder.cardll.removeAllViews();
        for (Student s:        ec.studentlist) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setText( s.getName());
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.cardll.addView(tv);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do this wrong. You have to change ListView to RecyclerView. CardView can be Item which is used by RecyclerView

Comment: I am using RecyclerView. That's where the onBindViewHolder comes from. I just can't find a way to recycle the views in the holder when the views are dynamic.

Comment: maybe this method public int getItemViewType(int position) from adapter is what do you want

Comment: I thought about that. But I don't think it's feasible to include an infinite number of item types depending on how many students there are in the class.